# Get path node js (nw)

Tags: javascript, node.js, nwjs

I would like to retrieve the directory where the .app file is launched for example if I run my **nwjs.app** from */Users/thomas/Desktop/nwjs.app* I would like that in my program I can retrieve it.

**process.cwd()** returns the correct directory when I run from *./nwjs* but not when I put the app.nw archive it returns me: */private/var/folders/xl/mm8951l946xbc0rxd91mmr_00000gn/T/.io .nwjs.nwjs.9p38hJ*

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `path = require('path');` then "rootFolder = path.resolve("..");" or "rootFolder = path.resolve(".");" I'm on windows, so please test and tell us what worked

Comment: also try `process.execPath` and `path.dirname(process.execPath);`

Comment: @MaherFattouh every commands return "/private/var/folders/xl/mm8951l946xbc0rxd91mmr_00000gn/T/.io.nwjs.nwjs.dY0CgO"

Comment: I fired up a macOS VM and downloaded nwjs just for this, see my answer. it worked!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41599125/1237812

Answer (score 0):

```
path = require('path');
nwjsPath = path.resolve(process.execPath, '../../../../../../../')
```

I have *nwjs* in (*/Users/Maher/Desktop/nwjs-sdk-v0.20.0-osx-x64*)

I have *app.nw* in *Contents/Resources*

the code above returns **"/Users/Maher/Desktop/nwjs-sdk-v0.20.0-osx-x64/nwjs.app"**

Comment: Unfortunately I still get: /private/var/folders/xl/mm8951l946xbc0rxd91mmr_00000gn/T/AppTranslocation/15D18B6C-5D49-4990-BAD6-2A91E9B00FF5/d/nwjs.app

Comment: strange, I tried it my self and it worked! try changing the location of nwjs and see what happens. also what macOS and nwjs versions are you running?